# Can cypress.json be at the same level as the src folder

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

The FE team just restructured the front end folders and moved the cypress tests into a folder called e2e with the cypress.json inside of it.

```
    e2e / src / integration / test.feature
                            / test / test.ts
       / cypress.json
```

The cypress.json file references the folders:

```
    "defaultCommandTimeout": 5000,
    "pageLoadTimeout": 10000,
    "responseTimeout": 10000,
    "requestTimeout": 5000,
    "ignoreTestFiles": "**/*.{js,ts,md}",
    "testFiles": "./src/integration/**/*.feature",
    "viewportHeight": 1920,
    "viewportWidth": 1080,
    "fileServerFolder": ".",
    "fixturesFolder": "./src/fixtures",
    "integrationFolder": "./src/integration"
```

But when starting cypress, none of the feature files show up.
Does the cypress.json need to be at the same level of the e2e folder?
Anything else that would prevent the feature files in the integration folder to show up?
NOTE: everything was working file before the restructure with a more traditional folder structure.
Folder was called cypress and cypress.json was at the same level as the cypress folder.

Comment: So actually, realized that starting cypress will create an empty cypress.json at the top folder. Is there any way to pass in the cypress.json we'd like to use when running cypress open?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can point to your specific cypress file:
cypress open --config-file ./apps/e2e/cypress.json
Still trying to get feature files picked up but at least it's picking up my cypress file.